# How to build a VPN in azure to have a public static IP wherever I travel

Tags: azure, vpn, tunnel, tunneling

I need to connect to a service that allows only whitelisted IP-s. The problem is that I work in various places with various IP-s.

I want to build a azure based vpn that would expose me with a static public IP. The goal is to configure it without the need to VM.

So far I have created a Virtual Network with VPN gateway and I can connect to it however I cannot force my computer to use that connection as an exit to the internet. Is building such thing even possible? If yes? How?

How can I create such solution (without using VM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can connect to it however I cannot force my computer to use that
>   connection as an exit to the internet.

It is a by design behavior, we **can't** force network traffic through Azure VPN as an exit to the Internet.

[image]

> How can I create such solution (without using VM)?

Do you mean you don't want to remote this VM then connect to this service?

If I understand it correctly, I think we can deploy a RRAS server in Azure, and works as proxy, route network traffic to that service.

As a reference here is a doc [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-forced-tunneling)

Comment: Hm.. that is what I was afraid but had hope that it sould be doable. As an exercise I wanted to do it without VM. In this case I'll go with VM. Thank you for the answer.